# qooxdoo table with remote model, Inserting new row on UI and update on server

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

Using this I successfully able to use qooxdoo to retrive data from my database

http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/0.8/remote_table_model

But my problem is, I want to Insert new Data into remote model and
update it on the server and also update it on the Table widget.

But remote data model seems to be totally incomplete, it doesn't even
offer addRows or addRowsAsMapArray function as Simple Model so how can
I achieve this?

Comment: Are you still using qooxdoo 0.8?! Because the current link to this document is http://manual.qooxdoo.org/1.5.x/pages/widget/table_remote_model.html (don't think much changed, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that feature is missing. As a workaround, you could add the data to the server and reload the table. As only parts of the table should be loaded, this is not as bad as it might sound in the first place. Updating your data is also not part of the API but thats hard anyway because the framework does not know you server interace.